# Filter out duplicates of dataframe on certain column, replace all other columns with the value which isn't zero

Tags: r, replace, duplicates, data.table, purrr

I have the following data structure to work with:

```
df.list <- list(df1, df2)
ids <- c(ID, ID2)

[[1]]
id  foo lorem1968 lorem1969
1   1         6        0
1   2         0        17
3   3         0         0
3   4         8        19
5   5         0        20

[[2]]
id2 ipsum lorem1969 lorem1970
1    11         0        22
2    12        17         0
2    13         0        24
3    14        19         0
3    15        20         0
```

Each id represents different households. I have different datasets I merge with different columns for these observations, hence the duplicate values.

I would like now to filter out all duplicates of the id column and replace the 0 value in all columns with the corresponding values which aren't zero.

In my code I excluded the first column since these will be my ids. The original id columns are named in a weird way so I'll have to use "tolower" to get the right columns.

I attempted the following, using `purrr::map2(), as.data.table` but get an error.

```
test <- purrr::map2(df.list, tolower(ids), function(x, y) {
    as.data.table(x)[, .SD[which.max(abs(x[,-1]))], by=y] 
    })


 Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double' 
12.
stop(err$message, call. = FALSE) 
11.
.checkTypos(e, names_x) 
10.
value[[3L]](cond) 
9.
tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]]) 
8.
tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers) 
7.
tryCatch(eval(.massagei(isub), x, ienv), error = function(e) .checkTypos(e, 
    names_x)) 
6.
`[.data.table`(.SD, which.max(abs(x[-1]))) 
5.
.SD[which.max(abs(x[-1]))] 
4.
`[.data.table`(as.data.table(x), , .SD[which.max(abs(x[-1]))], 
    by = y) 
3.
as.data.table(x)[, .SD[which.max(abs(x[-1]))], by = y] 
2.
.f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) 
1.
purrr::map2(my.list2, tolower(id.ind.interv), function(x, y) {
    as.data.table(x)[, .SD[which.max(abs(x[-1]))], by = y]
})
```

I also examined my actual dfs with `sapply(df, is.numeric)` but all of them are. Is there a more direct way of just replacing zero values with the corresponding other values by id?

Thanks so much guys!

Comment: You can specify `.SDcols`

Comment: You can try `lapply(df.list, function(dat) as.data.table(dat)[, lapply(.SD, max), by = names(dat)[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @akrun!!

```
lapply(df.list, function(dat) as.data.table(dat)[, lapply(.SD, max), by = eval(names(dat)[1])])
```

worked! Only had to add in the `eval()` at the end so data.table would process it correctly. Cheers :)